# how to representative sampling a dataframe in csv using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, distribution, sampling

I have a dataframe like below,

```
print (df)
  column 1 column 2  column 3
0   mobile        a    Blanks
1   mobile        b    Blanks
2   mobile        c   cricket
3   laptop        d   cricket
4    phone        e  football
5    phone      NaN  football
6    phone        g  football
7    phone        h  football
```

I want only one row without blanks with respect to c1 column
After applying sampling method the df should be

```
c1      c2    c3
mobile   a    Blanks
mobile   c    cricket
laptop   d    cricket
phone    g    football
```

Please tell me which sampling method will be suitable for this.

Comment: `mobile` appears not once but twice???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all rows with `NaN`s by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

If need only one random row by grouping by `column 1` and `column 3` you can use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for random position by [`numpy.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)

```
df = df.dropna()

df = df.groupby(['column 1','column 3'], as_index=False) \
       .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(x)), 1)]) \
       .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  column 1 column 2  column 3
0   laptop        d   cricket
1   mobile        b    Blanks
2   mobile        c   cricket
3    phone        h  football
```

Or use [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html):

```
df = df.groupby(['column 1','column 3'], as_index=False) \
       .apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1)) \
       .reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  column 1 column 2  column 3
0   laptop        d   cricket
1   mobile        b    Blanks
2   mobile        c   cricket
3    phone        g  football
```

Comment: what can I do if I need that sample for n=2 (2 representation).
I am getting this error:

Comment: Then change `x.sample(n=1)` to `x.sample(n=2)`, but need in each group at least `2` rows.

Comment: And in first solution need `.apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.random.choice(np.arange(len(x)), 2)])`

Comment: Also if need group by only first column change `df.groupby(['column 1','column 3'], as_index=False)` to `df.groupby(['column 1'], as_index=False)`

Comment: thanks for your solution, I changed it to x.sample(n=,replace=True)), now it is generating a sampled output, can you tell me what is happening when replace=True

Comment: can you give me a link where I can understand more about this sample function

Comment: You can check [`sample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and in doc check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#selecting-random-samples)

Answer (score 0):

Here code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('44652428.tsv')

print(df.groupby('column 1').first().reset_index())
```

Here output:

```
  column 1 column 2  column 3
0   laptop        d   cricket
1   mobile        a    Blanks
2    phone        e  football
```

Here input `44652428.tsv`:

```
column 1    column 2    column 3
mobile  a   Blanks
mobile  b   Blanks
mobile  c   cricket
laptop  d   cricket
phone   e   football
phone   NaN football
phone   g   football
phone   h   football
```

Here links to documentation on [read_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_table.html), [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).